# How do I insert what's after the slash in a domain into the php script on the page?

Tags: php, sendmail

I am not proficient in PHP which will be obvious. I'm using an email php script shown here http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-to-use-sendmail-with-php

Here's what I am trying to do. When someone visits http://example.com/jeremy I want the results of the form to be to be sent to jeremy@domain.com . If someone goes to /brian I want the results sent to brian@domain.com .

So in the script I put this code in for the email line

```
$myemail = "$request_url=ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');echo.$request_url;@domain.com";
```

but that gives me this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /email_form.php on line 78
```

I feel like I am close but I just can't figure it out. What should I use? Thanks for you patience and response.

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntactical glitches. I'll break down and clean up your code to what you probably intended to do:

```
$request_url = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');
$myemail = $request_url . '@domain.com';
```

Of course you can write down this as a one-liner:

```
$myemail = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') . '@domain.com';
```

Comment: I put that code in (changed it to my specific domain of course) and while there is no error it doesn't send the email either. From playing around with it seems it must have "" around it to work

Like $myemail = "ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') . '@domain.com'";

But that causes errors again.

I'd like to send it to another normal email address as well so I can look and see where it's trying to send the other one but when I take your code and  say ,example@domain.com that gives an error too. I cannot send to two recipients anymore to test it out.

Comment: When I do this on the page it works great but when I try to put the code you provided into the mail php script it does not send the email.

[code]<?php
$request_url=ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') . '@domain.com';
echo $request_url;
?>[/code]

Comment: Jeremy, that's another concern. What this script explains so far is _how to compose the email address_ the way you wanted it. I thought that was your main problem. Sending emails is explained here [http://de2.php.net/manual/de/book.mail.php](http://de2.php.net/manual/de/book.mail.php). Please have a look on that - you'll probably end up in something like `mail($myemail, 'Subject', 'Body');`.

Comment: I really appreciate your continued help. I'm using the script provided by hostgator. If I manually hardcode an email address in there it works fine. Like this.

$myemail = "jeremy@domain.com";

but when I put in this no email is sent.

$myemail = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') . '@domain.com';

even though if I say <?php $myemail = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') . '@domain.com'; echo $myemail ?> somewhere on the page it does show the email address I want the form sent to.

It's got to be so close but I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: It seems you're mixing up a couple of things. Please clarify your situation by telling us _what kind of form_ (or values) you're willing to send and _where you expect this to happen in your code_ so far.

Comment: The website I posted in my original post has the exact script I'm using. For the email address I'm putting 

$myemail = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') . '@domain.com';

but that does not work. For some reason the email is not sent. I know the script works because if I hardcode in an email address then it does send it as expected. As a test I put ?php
$myemail=ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') . '@domain.com';
echo $myemail;
? on the page just to see if the proper email address was being populated and it is.

Comment: So I do not understand why it is not working. I think I need to surround your code in parenthesis like this $myemail = "ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') . '@domain.com'"; but that creates an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: Sorry to post again but I've discovered something. I put this in the code $myemail2 = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') . '@domain.com'; and then $myemail = "jeremy@mydomain.com,.$myemail2."; and what I received in my email was .email_form.php?do=send@domain.com  So it is pulling the wrong information. Instead of getting what's after the slash domain.com/jeremy it is getting some header code when the form is sent or something I don't understand. I hope this makes the issue clearer. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: I figured it out. By defining the variable in the php script it was pulling the incorrect uri information. I defined the variable on the page and then the variable placed in the php code is correct. Thank you for all your help!